# Errors while trying to get a basic dice program to work

Tags: c#, random

I'm sure this is trivial, but I can't figure it out. My teacher just showed us how to create random numbers using a .Next(); statement last night and I was told to write an assignment that stimulates two dice rolls and compares them. I wrote out the code and everything was working fine until I added dice2 to my console.writeline. What am I missing here?

Once I added dice2 I got the following errors and they all disapear when I remove dice2.

1. ) expected
2. ; expected
3. Invalid expression term ')'
4. Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

Here is my code

```
Random m = new Random();
Random m1 = new Random();
string again;

do
{

    int dice1 = m.Next(1, 6);
    int dice2 = m1.Next(1, 6);

    if (dice1 == 6 && dice2 == 6)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You rolled boxcars");
    }
    else if (dice1 == 1 && dice2 == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You rolled snake-eyes");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You rolled a {0} and a {1}", dice1 dice2);
    }
        Console.WriteLine("Again? (y/n)");
    again = Console.ReadLine();

} while (again == "y");
```

edit

After adding the comma I noticed that I was getting the same values so after doing some research I deleted Random m1 = new Random(); and changed int dice2 = m1.Next(1, 6); to int dice2 = m.Next(1, 6); and it worked. I then realized that it wasn't giving me any 6 values so I changed it to (1, 7) and it worked perfectly

Comment: Because you're creating two `Random` instances at the same time they'll almost always have the same seed, and as such generate the exact same sequence of random numbers, so your two values will always match.  Rather than creating two random number generators and getting one value from each, create just one random number generator and ask it for two random numbers.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that. I deleted Random m1 = new Random(); and changed int dice2 = m1.Next(1, 6); to int dice2 = m.Next(1, 6); and it worked perfectly. I then realized that it wasn't giving me any 6 values so I changed it to (1, 7) and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a comma between `dice1` and `dice2` on this line:

```
Console.WriteLine("You rolled a {0} and a {1}", dice1 dice2);
```

Should be:

```
Console.WriteLine("You rolled a {0} and a {1}", dice1, dice2);
```

Comment: Wow, I feel pretty dumb for missing that. I tried rewriting the code two times and couldn't figure it out. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a comma:

```
Console.WriteLine("You rolled a {0} and a {1}", dice1, dice2);
//                                                  ^^^
```